# Inserting a new set of nodes inside root node

Tags: php, xml

My XML is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customers>
<customer>
    <custID>
        1001
    </custID>
    <fname>
        Lama
    </fname>
    <lname>
        Lai
    </lname>
    <email>
        test@hotmail.com
    </email>
    <password>
        qwer
    </password>
</customer>
</Customers>
```

My php code is as follows:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load ("../../data/customer.xml");
$customer = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName("customer");
```

and the part to save the detail is as follows:

```
$customerNew = $xmldoc->createElement("customer");
        //$customersTAB = $xmldoc->Customers();
        //$customerTAB->appendChild($customerNew);

        $customerNewFN = $xmldoc->createElement("fname");
        $customerNewFNNode = $xmldoc->createTextNode($firstname);
        $customerNewFNNode = $customerNewFN->appendChild($customerNewFNNode);
        $customerNewFN = $customerNew->appendChild($customerNewFN);

        $customerNewLN = $xmldoc->createElement("lname");
        $customerNewLNNode = $xmldoc->createTextNode($lastname);
        $customerNewLNNode = $customerNewLN->appendChild($customerNewLNNode);
        $customerNewLN = $customerNew->appendChild($customerNewLN);

        $customerNewEmail = $xmldoc->createElement("email");
        $customerNewEmailNode = $xmldoc->createTextNode($email);
        $customerNewEmailNode = $customerNewEmail->appendChild($customerNewEmailNode);
        $customerNewEmail = $customerNew->appendChild($customerNewEmail);

        $customerNewPass = $xmldoc->createElement("password");
        $customerNewPassNode = $xmldoc->createTextNode($password);
        $customerNewPassNode = $customerNewPass->appendChild($customerNewPassNode);
        $customerNewPass = $customerNew->appendChild($customerNewPass);

        $customerNew  = $xmldoc->fir appendChild($customerNew);

        $xmldoc->save('../../data/sample.xml');
```

I'm trying to create a completely new customer node INSIDe the Customers node. I can't seem to do that. I've pretty sure I've got the inner nodes properly mapped out but I can seemed to append as another child of Customers node.

The overall result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customers>
    <customer>
        <custID>
                1001
        </custID>
        <fname>
                Lama
        </fname>
        <lname>
                Lai
        </lname>
        <email>
                test@hotmail.com
        </email>
        <password>
                qwer
        </password>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <custID>
                1002
        </custID>
        <fname>
                Lama2
        </fname>
        <lname>
                Lai2
        </lname>
        <email>
                test2@hotmail.com
        </email>
        <password>
                qwer2
        </password>
    </customer>
</Customers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is first get the `<customer>` elements and then get the first one to be able to get the parent.

```
$customer = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName("customer");
```

The variable `$customer` is a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php)

You can get the first item from that list using `$customer->item(0)`, then get the `parentNode` (which will be `<Customers>` and then use [insertBefore](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php) to insert your new element:

`$customer->item(0)->parentNode->insertBefore($customerNew);`

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ofZgC)

Comment: Tried your code, it works well for the first time, then it would overwrite the 2nd node it when tried another time. is there a way to just add on top of that so that there is a third node?

Comment: my bad it works. Just that i made small changes in between and was loading a different file. Thank you so much!